# What do the following messages in dmesg mean?

Tags: networking, wifi, logs, terminology, qos

These following two lines were in my dmesg:

```
[xx] wlan0: AP has invalid WMM params (AIFSN=0 for ACI 0), will use 2
[xx] wlan0: AP has invalid WMM params (missing AC 0), using defaults
```

Another one:

```
[xx] wlan0: AP has invalid WMM params (CWmin/max=0/0 for ACI 3), using defaults
```

Answer (score 2):

These messages are all related to the **AP** (wifi) **A**ccess **P**oint (device) your system is connected to.

**WMM** stands for the [**W**i-fi **M**ulti**m**edia extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Multimedia_Extensions) which provides basic **Q**(uality)**o**(f)**s**(ervice) features, among which :

- The **A**rbitration **I**nter-**F**rame **S**pacing (**AIFS**) which specifies a wait time for data frames.
  Valid values being generally >  0, your system simply warns you that it is not pleased with the default or preset null value and arbitrarily changed it to 2.
- **AC** is the **A**ccess **C**ategory (Background, Best-Effort, Video, Voice).
  Nothing being specified, your system went to default, (Which one ? It depends on your system I presume)
- **CWmin** and **CWmax** represent the minimum (the initial random backoff wait time for retry of a transmission) and maximum (upper limit for the doubling of the random backoff value) **C**ontention **W**indow
  These values should obsiously be > 0 (not to say CWmin <= CWmax) which does not appear to be the case on your system which will use default settings for these parameters.

Well in short, provided default settings are pertinent, nothing really to worry about… except if you need better performances or different priority settings, in which case, you might need [a deeper understanding of Qos features.](https://www.cwnp.com/uploads/802-11_arbitration.pdf)